# How to enable "Global default typing" in Jackson via "jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder"

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am using Jackson within a Spring application. I am configuring Jackson via a bean:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer configureJackson() {
        return jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder -> {
            jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToEnable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

    jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        };
    }
}
```

Now i want to configure "Global default typing" - i want that all serialized objects contain type information.
I did not find any suitable "Feature" and i don't know if `jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.defaultTyping(??)` could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
  @Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer configureJackson() {

    return jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder -> {

      TypeResolverBuilder<?> typeResolver = new ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder(OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE);
      typeResolver = typeResolver.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
      typeResolver = typeResolver.inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY);

      jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.defaultTyping(typeResolver);
    };
  }
```

This is equivalent to

```
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, WRAPPER_ARRAY);
```